# Algorithm to calculate powers

Tags: algorithms, exponentiation, puzzle

Is it possible to write an algorithm that uses only multiplication and addition to calculate $a^b$ where both a and b are real numbers?

Comment: Do you want *exact* results, or do want something accurate to an arbitrary number of digits?

Comment: @anorton, anything accurate to an arbitrary number of digits.

Comment: Does division count? (It should, in my opinion, since we're dealing with real numbers anyway.)

Comment: @Ian, sure, you can multiply by the inverse of a number. Subtraction also counts if you add a negative number.

Comment: @Guacho I think you should change the title, as you're not looking for the exponent $b$, but the power $a^b$.

Comment: The usual algorithm for \** in floating point arithmetic is $a^b = \exp(b \ln(a))$. $\exp$ and $\ln$ can both be computed fairly quickly using their Taylor series expansions and some preprocessing tricks. For example, before using the series expansion one should first repeatedly multiply or divide $a$ by some (preferably large) number $c$ whose logarithm is known, to get $1<d<3/2$ with $c^nd=a$. Then $\ln(a)=\ln(c^n d)=n \ln(c) + \ln(d)$, and so $a^b = \exp(b \ln(a)) = \exp(b (n \ln(c) + \ln(d)))$. Now all you need to do is accurately compute $\ln(d)$ and the exponential.

Comment: (Cont.) Then we can efficiently compute $\ln(d)$ by Taylor series expansion. To finish up, we efficiently compute $\exp(x)$ as follows. Write $x=\lceil x \rceil + y$, then $\exp(x)=\exp(\lceil x \rceil) \exp(y)$. Compute $\exp(y)$ with the Taylor series (we can hardcode the convergence rate of this, since $y \in (-1,0]$), and then compute $\exp(\lceil x \rceil)$ by first very accurately computing $e$ and then using modular exponentiation.

Comment: @Ian Now turn that into pseudocode.